# How to configure nodes on Cosmos DB for mongo vCore?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi, azure-cosmosdb-mongovcore

I was trying to create a new Cosmos DB for Mongo vCore account and I am not able to find a way to configure nodes as mentioned in the documentation?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSKVR.png)

Also is autoscale supported on Mongo vCore?

I followed the steps given in the quick start docs

Comment: fyi this is off-topic here, as it's not a programming question. I suggest starting with the published documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the portal you need to select shards under the advanced tab, , we will update the documentation to reflect this change. Shards is often referred as nodes.[image]

Autoscale for Cosmos DB for MongoDB vCore is not supported yet.

Comment: fyi the question is off-topic - best to just point to docs in a comment and vote-to-close